# Cannot install BS4 and cannot import/use any other packages in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Sucessfully installed numpy, but when i import it in a program, it shows the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.(specified module cannot be found)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/devan/PycharmProjects/PyTest/test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in PyCharm 2019.1 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234). Early Access Preview is available here https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/.